# adding a trigger in mysql to change a content on update

Tags: mysql, database

I want to add a mysql trigger on update function.
This should be triggered on updating a specific column of one table say 'available from teachers' and update a specific column of another table say 'available from subjects'. How is this achievable?

I believe checking for change in the old and new field after update of teachers table to update the available column of subjects would do it.

```
IF NOT (NEW.teachers.available <=> OLD.teachers.available) THEN
  SET NEW.subject.available = NEW.teachers.available;
END IF;;
```

It should be something like this right?